# Not able to change permission of a file to add +x

Tags: permissions, ntfs, chmod

I am not able to understand what is the issue here ?

```
vks@vksTP:~/dropbox/shells$ ll sssh.sh
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1218 Mar 17 17:58 sssh.sh
vks@vksTP:~/dropbox/shells$ sudo chmod +x sssh.sh
vks@vksTP:~/dropbox/shells$ ll sssh.sh
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1218 Mar 17 17:58 sssh.sh
```

I am not able to change the permission of the to +x.

Edit:

I have a dual boot machine, and I share the same dropbox folder. This dropbox folder is on a ntfs mount of my D drive for windows. Following are the entries from fstab

```
/dev/sda2 /mnt/C ntfs-3g rw,user,fmask=0111,dmask=0000 0 0  
/dev/sda3 /mnt/D ntfs-3g rw,user,fmask=0111,dmask=0000 0 0
```

I am not able to add +x to anyfile in /mnt/D

Comment: What are the permissions for the directory? Does dropbox support permissions at all?

Comment: Just checked mine, dropbox does support my +x parameter

Comment: @viv assumed you used Sudo to change as it is root

Comment: Are you able to chmod any other file on the same partition where the file is? If not, maybe you need to edit your fstab file and add the exec option.

Comment: By default you can't have executable in NTFS parition. Need to edit fstab file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fmask` is set to `0111`, meaning the lowermost bit of file permissions will be cleared. This bit is the `x`. Set the mask to e.g. `002` to just clear the write bit for `others`, and leave the `r` and `x` bits intact.